# web server returns "broken pipe" error when constantly reloading page

Tags: c, sockets, raspberry-pi, webserver, raspbian

I found a partial solution for the last couple errors and what I did was just create a thread pool instead of creating new threads and killing them each connection. Now i don't have those weird errors but I am having a problem listed below.

I'm working on a C web server on my raspberry pi and i'm able to handle multiple web page requests but when the client decides to reload the page really fast, after a couple of reloads, the web server crashes and gdb gives me the error: "broken pipe".

Here's the code for the server: https://hastebin.com/wuzepotiko.c

I think the problem might be with the read error handling because when I use gdb it gives me the error:

```
Thread 13 "webServer" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
[Switching to Thread 0xb161f440 (LWP 23260)]
__libc_write (nbytes=0, buf=0x22cc0 <httpResponse>, fd=7)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:26
26  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c: No such file or directory.
```

I know it's a ton of code but I've been stuck on this for a while now. Even if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I advice you to use C++ and some existing web framework. Otherwise you will end up with server supporting directory traversal, buffer overflows etc. even using demo quality [sample code from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/server/small/http_server_small.cpp) could give you stable starting point. Be careful with the sample I provided - it uses single threaded approach so do not use blocking system calls in it.

Comment: "malloc(); unsorted double linked list corrupted" this happens sometimes when the metadata that the function ```free()``` writes on memory after deallocating are corrupted . For example , in the case of a heap overflow. 
Maxim is giving you a good advice , but , in case you want to keep working on your code , may I suggest that you post additionnal info from GDB ? That would give us some clues.

Comment: @AmineBensalem I didn't know that I could use a debugger. I'll add the debugging info to the post once i'm able to get something!

Comment: @AmineBensalem, I've added the gdb debugging info for one of the errors. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I want to keep going with the code I have already and I’m pretty sure I’ll be able to find a way to fix directory traversal and buffer overflows but thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: @logsInMyEyes69 hi , there are multiple issues with your code , what you've added with the debug infos misses the stack trace . But , for example in the line `char *endDir = strrchr(recvLineGET, ' ');` , `endDir` can be NULL because strrchr doesn't parse your buffer correctly . But this is really the tip of the iceberg, 
Also , reset your buffers before you write to them , or you'll have some garbage from previous requests that will mess your string operations on them. share a minimal reproductible example of your errors , because I don't have any malloc errors yet

Comment: @AmineBensalem, I was able to find a solution for the errors but the web server still crashes. I also did what you said and used memset() on as many buffers as I could. Check out the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to the question. Since the write function was sending a broken pipe error to the kernel, which told the kernel to quit the process, i used the send function which allowed me to prevent signals being sent to the kernel and now it works! Thank you to everyone who helped me fix my problems!